# Plotly update nested argument via updatemenus

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I would like to create a dropdown menu using [updatemenus](https://plotly.com/r/reference/layout/updatemenus/) from R Plotly to be able to change the source image in a plot.

This is what I have done so far, without success:

```r
library(plotly)
library(magrittr)

img1 <- "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/dc04a25fbabbffc1f1b7c6a3362bfae4?s=256&d=identicon&r=PG"
img2 <- "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/bc680ed8d2555accacebc0fe2d8c9691?s=256&d=identicon&r=PG"

plot_ly(x = 1:5, y = 1:5, type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers') %>% 
  layout(
    images = list(
      list(
        source =  img1,
        xref = "x",
        yref = "y",
        x = 3,
        y = 4,
        sizex = 2,
        sizey = 2
      )
    ),
    updatemenus = list(
      list(
        y = 1,
        buttons = list(
          list(method = "restyle",
               args = list(list(images = list(list(source = img1)))),
               label = "img1"),
          list(method = "restyle",
               args = list(list(images = list(list(source = img2)))),
               label = "img2")
        )
      )
    )
  )
```

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is probably more than one way to do this, but this works. For layout updates, you're usually going to use the method `relayout`. You need to provide all of the information, as well (i.e., `x`, `y`, `xref`, etc.).

```
library(plotly)

img1 <- "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/dc04a25fbabbffc1f1b7c6a3362bfae4?s=256&d=identicon&r=PG"
img2 <- "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/bc680ed8d2555accacebc0fe2d8c9691?s=256&d=identicon&r=PG"

imgOne = list( # create image expectations
  list(
    source =  img1,
    xref = "x", yref = "y",
    x = 3, y = 4,
    sizex = 2, sizey = 2))

imgTwo = list( # create image expectations
  list(
    source =  img2,
    xref = "x", yref = "y",
    x = 3, y = 4,
    sizex = 2, sizey = 2))

plot_ly(x = 1:5, y = 1:5, type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers') %>% 
  layout(
    images = imgOne,
    updatemenus = list(
      list(
        y = 1,
        active = 0,
        buttons = list(
          list(label = "None",
               method = "relayout",
               args = list(list(images = c()))),
          list(label = "img1",
               method = "relayout",
               args = list(list(images = imgOne))),
          list(label = "img2",
               method = "relayout",
               args = list(list(images = imgTwo)))
        ))))
```

There are a few `method` options for `updatemenus`. [You can read more about that here.](https://plotly.com/r/reference/#layout-updatemenus-items-updatemenu-buttons-items-button-method)

[image]